# Python3:How to keep-alive dropbox.files_upload() . So to download and upload at the same time?

Tags: python, dropbox

I want to download a file from the internet and upload it to dropbox at the same time . I am downloading file as chunks and after every completed chunk I want it to upload it to dropbox.

```
import multiprocessing as m
import requests as rr
import dropbox
url='http://www.onirikal.com/videos/mp4/battle_games.mp4'
db=dropbox.Dropbox(Accesstoken)
def d(url):
    r=rr.get(url,stream=True)
    with open('file.mp4','wb')as f:
        for a in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1000000):
            if a:
                f.write('')
                f.write(a)

def u():
    try:
        with open('file.mp4','rb')as ff:
            db.files_upload(ff.read(),'/file.mp4')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
if __name__=='__main__':
    p=m.Pool()
    re= p.apply_async(d,[url])
    ree=p.apply_async(u)
    re.get(timeout=10)
    ree.get(timeout=10)
```

But the uploaded file is having a size 0byte

**EDIT**

I am using `f.write('')` to save space on the server as i am only getting 512mb as storage

Comment: Somebody reply !!!

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/General-Discussion/How-to-keep-alive-file-upload-connection/m-p/286821#M107

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use multiprocessing for this.  Instead, simply download the chunks as you are already doing, and immediately call [`upload_chunk(a, len(a), offset, upload_id)`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs/python).  You do not need the temporary file on disk.

Comment: The documentation is a little confusing can you give me an example

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do something like this

```
r=rr.get(url,stream=True)
db.files_upload(r.content,'/file.mp4')
```

To upload directly without making a file. In the case that you want to upload as a stream or in chunks, I'd imagine you would need to do something like the following:

```
from io import BytesIO
import requests
import dropbox

client = dropbox.client.DropboxClient(access_token)

r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
with BytesIO(r.content) as bytes_stream:
    client.get_chunked_uploader(bytes_stream, len(r.content))
    while uploader.offset < len(r.content):
        try:
            upload = uploader.upload_chunked()
        except dropbox.rest.ErrorResponse, e:
            # perform error handling and retry logic
    uploader.finish('/file.mp4')
```

I cannot verify either method as I cannot currently install the dropbox module, so you might need to tweak a few things.

Comment: Thanks.But can you look at this please  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51606801/python3-dropbox-uploading-error-using-api-v2